# Jquery Context undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-context

I am trying to implement the jquery context in my website and it keeps telling me that $.contextMenu is undefined.

My Code as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function(){
            $.contextMenu({
                selector: '.folders',
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    var m = "clicked: " + key;
                    window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

What Am I doing wrong please?

Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
UploadFile.html:42 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.Callbacks.jjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 
n.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.extend.readyjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 K
```

Thanks

Comment: Working for me any console error?

Comment: Console error is:
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionUploadFile.html:42 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 n.Callbacks.jjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 n.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 n.extend.readyjquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 K

Comment: for me its not working